# Soapclient passing the data for the body of request into __soapCall

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I'm integrating with a SOAP webservice from PHP - when calling the method using __soapcall and passing an array of data in an associative array.

I'm doing something wrong as the first parameter doesn't appear at all - and the second one is appearing with 'param1' as the tag name in the XML.

The code I'm using:

```
$soap = new SoapClient($apiURL, array('trace' => 1));
$value = 'ABCDEFG';

$data = array();
$data['keyname1'] = $value;             
$data['keyname2'] = 'testingtesting';               

$response = $soap->__soapCall('CheckAddress', $data);
```

But the request being sent to the server omits the keyname1 all together and has the value set as keyname2 in a tag labelled only as param1:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://example.com/ws/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns1:CheckAddress/><param1>testingtesting</param1>
```

In actual fact the parameters should be going inside the CheckAddress namespace also.

I'm not doing great at making sense of the documentation for the calls so any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably best not to use `$soap->__soapCall()`, as that's really a "low level API", and only useful when you are in a "non-WSDL mode":

https://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapcall.php

Why not try calling the `CheckAddress()` method on the `$soap` object, e.g.

```
$response = $soap->CheckAddress($value1, $value2, $value3);
$response = $soap->CheckAddress($data);
```

And if you're first argument uses a keyed array, you should be able to do:

```
$response = $soap->CheckAddress(['name' => 'value']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$data['keyname1'][0] = $value;             
$data['keyname2'][1] = 'testingtesting';
```

It should work